# Conversation history in Outlook 2010 (x64) with Office Communicator 2007 R2

Tags: 64-bit, ms-office-communicator, microsoft-office-2010, outlook-2010

Since upgrading from Office 2007 to Office 2010 (x64), conversation history from Office Communicator 2007 R2 no longer is saved into Outlook's Conversation History folder, even though Communicator states that a conversation was saved.

There was talk of this being an issue during the betas, and even some afterwards, but I've never really seen anybody say that there was a fix for this.

Has anybody come up with a way to configure Outlook (x64)/Office Communicator to work together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Communicator conversation history is enabled by an Outlook add-in. The current version of Communicator is 32 bit only. The add-in it ships with is 32 bit only. Unfortunately, that means it won't work on a 64 bit version of Outlook. Outlook 64-bit can only install 64-bit add-ins. It is for this reason that Microsoft recommends sticking with 32-bit versions of Office unless there is a need. The only big advantage of going 64-bit is to enable Excel spreadsheets over 2GB. If you don't have a need for this, why not install the 32-bit version of Office? It is supported on 64 bit machines.

The other option, unfortunately, is to wait and upgrade. Communicator 2010 should be out before too long and will likely include a 64-bit option.

Comment: +1, why even bother with 64 bit outlook? Do you need outlook to load 4GB of RAM? The only usage for 64-bit office is solely Excel with extreme large amounts of data

Comment: I am experiencing this exact same issue intermittently, and the resolution is to repair the Office Communicator installation, reboot the pc, and then it works. Only problem is that I've had to do it twice in the last month - anyone else see this?